# How to add a number from an HTML form to a number already in Database?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have an HTML form, which is sending data to a database via an "input.php" file which I have connected to my database.

What I wanted to accomplish, is that the data being sent to the database from the HTML form is all numbers. I wanted to know how I can code the input.php file so that when new numbers get submitted from the HTML form, and get sent to a value which already has a number, to add the two up.

For example, Person A fills out a number in the form on day one, per say 5. The next day, he submits the exact same field with the number 3. In the database, instead of overriding the first value, I want to add it up. So on day 1, the database should say "5", but on day 2, it should say "8".

Here is my bare-bones "input.php" file which I will use. The names for the fields will change in my finalized code.

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['last_name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);

// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES 
('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I thought maybe I could use some javascript validation, however that would be for validating the field, and not adding...so...

Thanks!

Comment: Before entering the record second time, you must retrieve the record from DB based on unique identifier, in your case it could be email. If you get back some value from DB on that particular email, then update the record else do a new insert. For example, user has already entered with email "test@gmail.com". Next time when he fills the form and clicks the submit button, in your index.php file write code to check if "test@gmail.com" exists in DB, if it exists, then return the index from DB and then write a SQL to update the same row with your new changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say the column name is `counts` which needs to be summed, and column index `id`, you could use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to update based on `id` if it's already exist, and insert a new row if it's not exist:

UPDATE: You don't need the `id` field in this situation, as you can automate it using an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

```
// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name, email, counts) VALUES 
('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$counts')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counts = counts + $counts";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Comment: OK. This seems like it is going to work. Just a question for you: The counts column name needs to be its own field on my HTML form, and in the database, correct? Other than that, I hope this works!

Comment: So I am using the code right now, however it seems to have some sort of syntax error. I have my database all set up with the colums id, first_name, last_name, email and counts, however it says there is some syntax error. I tries closing the values off with "; but nothing seems to work. Any ideas why it might be giving me that error?

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` implies there is a primary or unique key. I'd make this the email column. first/last names aren't unique.

Comment: Actually it was the syntax that was giving it errors. The `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and the argument should be on two different lines.

Answer (score 3):

Two things you need to do. First, verify if the record exists or not. Second, If exists update the record by adding the form input to the column . If not exists then insert new record with form input. To update you can write query like

```
 UPDATE TABLE_NAME
 SET column_to_update = column_to_update+form_input_number
 WHERE email=<email_address> ;
```

(assuming email is the primary key or replace email with any primary key field name)

Comment: Ok... I kind of see what you mean. Just a clarification that stuff with the _ are things I should replace, and what does form_input_number mean? Can I not just have it be updating the past form submission?

Comment: Yes, table_name is your table name , column_to_update is your actual column name that takes the number ; form_input_number is the number that the user submits in the form. You need to use this in the query to update the existing value.

Comment: Ok, but if form_input_number is a field, I use the field id, correct?

Comment: You use the field id to get it's value and assign it to a variable inside php file. Then, use this variable in the query.